# Обработка поворота экрана

Tags: ipad, ios, objective-c, изображения, iphone

Есть `uiimageview`, `uiscrollview`, `uislider` в портретной ориентации картинка отображается и зуммится как надо, однако, когда переворачиваешь в горизонтальную ориентацию, нужный уровень зума пропадает. Как правильно обработать поворот экрана, чтобы картинка просто поворачивалась без изменений?

Нужна хотя бы подсказка в нужном направлении =)

P.S.: сама картинка добавляется в `imageview`, через `storyboard;`

`slider` используется для зумма изображения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перегрузи методы в своем `NSVewController'е`

---

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
 - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

---

И сможешь вручную обрабатывать логику переворотов

Comment: я первым методом и пользовался) про второй кстати забыл, решил проблему в общем -допустил ошибку, при повороте изменялся размер imageview(сам не знаю зачем написал это), удлалил эту строчку из кода - все заработало)